Getting "Cannot use import statement outside a module" from Jest when running tests?
I'm running into a frustrating error during Jest tests: "SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module." This happens when I try to run npm test.
Test suite failed to run
Jest encountered an unexpected token

Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such syntax.

Out of the box Jest supports Babel, which will be used to transform your files into valid JS based on your Babel configuration.

By default "node_modules" folder is ignored by transformers.

Here's what you can do:
 • If you are trying to use ECMAScript Modules, see https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules for how to enable it.
 • If you are trying to use TypeScript, see https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started#using-typescript
 • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
 • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
 • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration
For information about custom transformations, see:
https://jestjs.io/docs/code-transformation

Details:

D:\Angular\ng-frontend\node_modules\@angular\core\fesm2022\testing.mjs:7
import { ɵDeferBlockState, ɵtriggerResourceLoading, ɵrenderDeferBlockState, ɵCONTAINER_HEADER_OFFSET, ɵgetDeferBlocks, ɵDeferBlockBehavior, InjectionToken, inject as inject$1, ɵNoopNgZone, NgZone, ɵEffectScheduler, ApplicationRef, ɵPendingTasks, getDebugNode, RendererFactory2, ɵdetectChangesInViewIfRequired, ɵstringify, ɵReflectionCapabilities, Directive, Component, Pipe, NgModule, ɵgetAsyncClassMetadataFn, ɵgenerateStandaloneInDeclarationsError, ɵUSE_RUNTIME_DEPS_TRACKER_FOR_JIT, ɵdepsTracker, ɵgetInjectableDef, resolveForwardRef, ɵNG_COMP_DEF, ɵisComponentDefPendingResolution, ɵresolveComponentResources, ɵRender3NgModuleRef, ApplicationInitStatus, LOCALE_ID, ɵDEFAULT_LOCALE_ID, ɵsetLocaleId, ɵRender3ComponentFactory, ɵcompileComponent, ɵNG_DIR_DEF, ɵcompileDirective, ɵNG_PIPE_DEF, ɵcompilePipe, ɵNG_MOD_DEF, ɵtransitiveScopesFor, ɵpatchComponentDefWithScope, ɵNG_INJ_DEF, ɵcompileNgModuleDefs, ɵclearResolutionOfComponentResourcesQueue, ɵrestoreComponentResolutionQueue, ɵinternalProvideZoneChangeDetection, ɵChangeDetectionScheduler, ɵChangeDetectionSchedulerImpl, Compiler, ɵDEFER_BLOCK_CONFIG, COMPILER_OPTIONS, Injector, ɵisEnvironmentProviders, ɵNgModuleFactory, ModuleWithComponentFactories, ɵconvertToBitFlags, InjectFlags, ɵsetAllowDuplicateNgModuleIdsForTest, ɵresetCompiledComponents, ɵsetUnknownElementStrictMode, ɵsetUnknownPropertyStrictMode, ɵgetUnknownElementStrictMode, ɵgetUnknownPropertyStrictMode, runInInjectionContext, EnvironmentInjector, ɵZONELESS_ENABLED, ɵflushModuleScopingQueueAsMuchAsPossible } from '@angular/core';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

> 1 | import 'jest-preset-angular/setup-jest';
    | ^
  2 | import './jest-global-mocks';

  at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1505:14)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/jest-preset-angular/setup-jest.js:3:24)
  at Object.<anonymous> (setup-jest.ts:1:1)

What I've Tried:

I followed a solution suggesting configuration changes for Jest to handle ES modules (but the error persists).
I've completely removed and reinstalled all project dependencies.
I've reviewed similar issues and documentation but haven't found a solution.
I even recreated the entire testing environment from scratch, following a different setup guide, but the error remains.
tried this i have reffered to this but still facing the issue

Relevant Configuration Files:

jest.config.js

const { pathsToModuleNameMapper } = require('ts-jest');

const { paths } = require('./tsconfig.json').compilerOptions;

/** @type {import('ts-jest/dist/types').JestConfigWithTsJest} */
module.exports = {
    preset: 'jest-preset-angular',
    moduleNameMapper: pathsToModuleNameMapper(paths, { prefix: '<rootDir>' }),
    setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/setup-jest.ts'],
    transformIgnorePatterns: [
      "/node_modules/",
      "<rootDir>/src/app/Config",
    ],
};



setup-jest.ts

import 'jest-preset-angular/setup-jest';
import './jest-global-mocks';


babel.config.js

module.exports = {
  presets: [
    ['@babel/preset-env', {
      targets: {
        node: 'current',
      },
    },],
    '@babel/preset-typescript',
  ],
  plugins: [
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { "legacy": true }]
  ]
};

Error Message:
Test suite failed to run

Jest encountered an unexpected token...

...

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

> 1 | import 'jest-preset-angular/setup-jest';
    | ^
  2 | import './jest-global-mocks';

Question:
How can I resolve this "Cannot use import statement outside a module" error within setup-jest.ts to run Jest tests successfully?
Additional Information:

I'm using Jest with TypeScript.
Any suggestions or insights into what might be causing this issue would be greatly appreciated.

